# making the button invisible , only to show when hovering on div or has text inside the input

Tags: html, css

I want to make this:

```
<div class-name="search">
  <input class-name="input"/>
  <button class-name="searchbutton> search </button>
</div>
```

but I want the button to be hidden, but when I hover the .search div or the .input has value in it, I want the button to appear, how can I do that?

Comment: What does your css look like?

Comment: Well the hover part should be trivial, that’s a simple use of the descendant combinator. The second part will only work if you make the input field `required`, so that you can then use the `:valid` pseudo class, in combination with the adjacent sibling combinator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start from :

```css
.input + button {
  display:none;
}
.input:hover + button ,.input:valid + button ,.input:focus + button {
  display:initial;
}
```

```html
<div class-name="search">
  <input class="input" required />
  <button class="searchbutton"> search </button>
</div>
```

---

Update from comment :

> Hi , I do not wish to make the input invisible, just the button, and I want the search div to be the element when it was hovered to be showing the button, can I do that? – Alex K

```css
.input + button {
  display:none;
}
.search:hover button {
  display:initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <input class="input" required />
  <button class="searchbutton"> search </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi , I do not wish to make the input invisible, just the button, and I want the search div to be the element when it was hovered to be showing the button, can I do that?

Comment: input is always visible here ?? Added a second snippet, but i'm not sure i understand you :) @AlexK

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with "display", first try making the searchbutton invisible by doing so...

```
<button class-name="searchbutton style="display: none;"> search </button>
```

Then you can check if the user is hovering over the search to make the button appear

```
.search:hover {
    .searchbutton {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Also check if the input is selected

```
.input {
    .searchbutton {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a simple JavaScript event to easily hide and show the button.

```
var search = document.querySelector("[class-name=search]");
var searchButton = document.querySelector("[class-name=searchbutton]");
var input = document.querySelector("[class-name=input]");
function showSearchButton() {
    searchButton.style.display = "block";
}
function hideSearchButton() {
    searchButton.style.display = "none";
}
search.onmouseover = showSearchButton;
input.onchange = showSearchButton;
//If you need to hide the element once they stop hovering
search.onmouseleave = hideSearchButton;
```

And for your CSS simply have the element hidden in the first place until it is hovered over or the input value changes.

```
[class-name=searchbutton] {
    display: none;
}
```

And I do recommend switching the "class-name" to simply "class" to make it easier to work with.